# BIND9 is running but not pinging my domain

Tags: dns, ubuntu-16.04, bind9

There  is a cloud server with IP 51.254.79.239
tt1.domain.com and tt2.domain.com are the name servers.

these are the zone options used

```
zone "domain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.domain.com";
};
zone "79.254.51.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        notify no;
        file "/etc/bind/db.51";
};
```

db.domain.com file

```
$TTL 14400
@    IN    SOA    tt1.domain.com.    root.domain.com. (
                                            17
                                            7200
                                            3600
                                            1209600
                                            180 )

@       14400   IN      NS              tt1.domain.com.
@       14400   IN      NS              tt2.domain.com.
tt1       14400   IN      A               51.254.79.239
tt2       14400   IN      A               51.254.79.239
@       14400   IN      A               51.254.79.239
mail    14400   IN      A               51.254.79.239
www     14400   IN      A               51.254.79.239
pop     14400   IN      A               51.254.79.239
ftp     14400   IN      A               51.254.79.239
@       14400   IN      MX      10      mail.domain.com.
@       14400   IN      TXT             "v=spf1 a mx ip4:51.254.79.239 ?all"
_dmarc  14400   IN      TXT             "v=DMARC1; p=none"
```

and the rev

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     tt1.domain.com. root.domain.com. (
                              16         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

      IN      NS      tt1.domain.com
      IN      NS      tt2.domain.com.


79.254.51   IN      PTR     tt1.domain.com.    ; 51.254.79.239
79.254.51   IN      PTR     tt2.domain.com.    ; 51.254.79.239
```

and it's Active: active (running) since Mon !

what it could be the problem that there is no ping answer on domain.com?!

Comment: domain.com is just a example

Comment: @CalleDybedahl Accusing somebody of lying because they used an example domain name in their question is way out of line. Questions should **not** depend on links to live sites/domains for you to debug them, if they do than the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Stop demanding people tell you their real domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Ping, if you use it with a hostname, *involves* looking up the name, but what you check is connectivity not DNS.

From your example, I can see, that both of your supposed "nameservers" are in fact the same server, as the one they are resolving. So I strongly assume, this "name server" is not authoritative, which means, no other name server in the hierarchy cares for the information it has. Did you think, you can just setup a nameserver and it would be queried for the domain, you told it?

You can easily check for the primary name server, with:

```
dig +short SOA domain.com
```

Or for all authoritative name servers with:

```
dig +short NS domain.com
```

`whois` also gives you this information.

Usually your provider gives you some interface to the resource records pertaining to your domain and updates the authoritative name servers accordingly, so you should probably look for this first.

You can then check, if everything with your changes is ok, with many online tools, for example this:

http://viewdns.info/dnsreport/